# get object and variables in aspectj using ProceedingJoinPoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

**I am using Spring MVC + AspectJ**

**@Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testLogger")
@TrxLogger
public String testLogger (
    @RequestParam(value = "optimumid", required = false) String optimumid,
    @RequestParam(value = "system", required = false) String system,
    @RequestParam(value = "accountnumber", required = false) String accountnumber,
    @RequestParam(value = "csrid", required = false) String csrid,
    @RequestParam(value = "paymentAccountNumber", required = false) String paymentAccountNumber,
    @RequestParam(value = "dummyData", required = false) String dummyData,
    @UserSession Optional<Session> session,
    HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

long nStartRequest = (new java.util.Date()).getTime();

String response = null;
GlobalStatus status = new GlobalStatus();
try {
    response = billPayService.testLogger(optimumid, system, accountnumber, csrid, paymentAccountNumber, dummyData);
    status.setStatusCode("OK");
    status.setStatusDesc("SUCCESS");

}catch (Exception e) {
    response = "BillPayController.testLogger() FAILED!";
    status.setStatusCode("ERROR");
    status.setStatusDesc("FAILURE");
}

    long nEndRequest = (new java.util.Date()).getTime(); 

return response ;

}
```

**@Aspect**

```
@Around("pcTrxLogger()")
public Object logMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    ...
    ...
    return null;
}
```

I can easily get all the parameters and response(`return response;`) in aspect using **ProceedingJoinPoint** but I am unable to get the following variable and object.

1. long nStartRequest = (new java.util.Date()).getTime();
2. GlobalStatus status = new GlobalStatus();
3. long nEndRequest = (new java.util.Date()).getTime();

How can we get these variables and object  in aspect (`logMethodCall()`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are local variables. You cannot access them unless your pass their value or reference to some middle object like the method's return value or stored in one of the method's arguments.

Note that you may have advised some other method where these variables don't exist, so why would it be possible to get them?

An alternative is to create those values in the advice itself. It doesn't seem like they depend in any way on what you do in the controller handler method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, every controller has its own local variable or object. one thing also confusing me , when other thing are accessible in proceeding join point , why these are not. even this method exposed in join point.

Comment: @Shahid The join point can only offer so much through reflection. You have access to `Method` object (to be invoked) itself, to the arguments passed when invoking it, the value returned if any, and the exceptions thrown if any. How could you ever know about any local variables created in this method or that method? That's not something that is possible in Java.